Keras NLP finetuning dataset incompatibility
I am running a python 3.11 instance on Google Colab to finetune a GPT-2 model. I install keras-nlp as follows, and my package versions become:
!pip install keras_nlp
print(tf.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)
print(keras_nlp.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

>>2.16.1
>>3.3.3
>>0.11.1
>>1

Below I prepared a minimally reproducible example that generates the error I get. By the way,the below code runs OK if I set up the environment as follows (from the original Google colab notebook), the problem with this version is that it does not recognise the GPU:
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras-nlp.git@google-io-2023 tensorflow-text==2.12
print(tf.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)
print(keras_nlp.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

>>2.12.1
>>2.12.0
>>0.5.0
>>0

So, it is a version compatibility issue I believe. The top configuration (that recognises GPU) runs fine until model fitting, and then throws the error below .
import numpy as np
import keras_nlp
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_text as tf_text
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.lite.python import interpreter
import time
from google.colab import files
from google.colab import runtime

gpt2_tokenizer = keras_nlp.models.GPT2Tokenizer.from_preset("gpt2_base_en")
gpt2_preprocessor = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLMPreprocessor.from_preset(
    "gpt2_base_en",
    sequence_length=512,
    add_end_token=True,
)
gpt2_lm = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLM.from_preset("gpt2_base_en", preprocessor=gpt2_preprocessor)

# Create dummy train data to highlight the error
training_list_manual = ['This is a sentence that I like', 'I went to school today.', 'I have a bike, you can ride it if you like.']
tf_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_list_manual)
processed_ds = tf_train_ds.map(gpt2_preprocessor, tf.data.AUTOTUNE).batch(64).cache().prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Attempt fine-tune
gpt2_lm.include_preprocessing = False

num_epochs = 1

lr = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.PolynomialDecay(
    5e-5,
    decay_steps=part_of_ds.cardinality() * num_epochs,
    end_learning_rate=0.0,
)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
gpt2_lm.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr),
    loss=loss,
    weighted_metrics=["accuracy"])

gpt2_lm.fit(processed_ds, epochs=num_epochs)

In the final .fit() line, I get the below Value error. I understand it does not like the 'x' value I try to input. However I am at a loss as to what to replace it with. Any ideas?
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling GPT2CausalLMPreprocessor.call().
Unsupported input for `x`. `x` should be a string, a list of strings, or a list of tensors. If passing multiple segments which should packed together, please convert your inputs to a list of tensors. Received `x={'token_ids': <tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=(None, None, 1024) dtype=int32>, 'padding_mask': <tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=(None, None, 1024) dtype=bool>}`

Arguments received by GPT2CausalLMPreprocessor.call():
  • x={'token_ids': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, 1024), dtype=int32)', 'padding_mask': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, 1024), dtype=bool)'}
  • y=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, 1024), dtype=int32)
  • sample_weight=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, 1024), dtype=bool)
  • sequence_length=None

The content of one data item looks as below. Does it expect me to only feed in the "token_ids" values to .fit()?
for example in tf_train_ds.take(1):
    print(gpt2_preprocessor(example))
({'token_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1024), dtype=int32, numpy=array([[50256,  1212,   318, ...,     0,     0,     0]], dtype=int32)>, 'padding_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1024), dtype=bool, numpy=array([[ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False]])>}, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1024), dtype=int32, numpy=array([[1212,  318,  257, ...,    0,    0,    0]], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1024), dtype=bool, numpy=array([[ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False]])>)


It worked when I did not try to preprocess the data beforehand (gpt2_lm.include_preprocessing = True), and batched tf_train_ds while fitting (gpt2_lm.fit(tf_train_ds.batch(64), epochs=num_epochs)) as follows:
# Attempt fine-tune
gpt2_lm.include_preprocessing = True

num_epochs = 1

lr = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.PolynomialDecay(
    5e-5,
    decay_steps=processed_ds.cardinality() * num_epochs,
    end_learning_rate=0.0,
)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
gpt2_lm.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr),
    loss=loss,
    weighted_metrics=["accuracy"])

gpt2_lm.fit(tf_train_ds.batch(64), epochs=num_epochs)

